# Should we bring down the iOS and iPhone tags for Cocoa and Objective-C ones when relevant?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms

Following a comment in Stack Overflow question *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19318119/how-to-display-json-data-in-uitableviewcell-in-ios*,

> What does this have to do with the iOS Operating system or the iphone device? If you tag your questions correctly you will get the best advice possible.

I'm wondering what the policy is concerning the common use of the iOS and iPhone tags related to questions about Objective-C or the Cocoa Framework.

Common use or relevant?

**Is this guy right or should we allow iOS/iPhone tags even for this kind of question?**

I am not talking about the Xcode tag (it's not a common tag).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Beyond [xcode], which [should only be used for questions regarding that IDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93974/xcode-is-just-an-ide), I'm a little more flexible in the use of the other tags.

Even though the question may not mention the OS specifically, an [ios] tag can provide important context for the question. A potential solution to a more generic problem might differ if the target platform is Mac or iOS (or even GNUstep, for the few questions I've seen asked about that), so such a tag can be helpful in many cases. It also provides greater exposure to a question, as there are many people who watch the core OS tags, like [ios] or [cocoa], and not the language-specific tags.

As far as the [iphone] tag, I explain a little bit of the history behind that in [my answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/159753/135615), but basically it was the go-to tag for iOS questions back when it was called iPhone OS. The inertia from that still carries over, so a lot of people still ask about iPhone development questions with that tag. At most, I try to add the [ios] tag to them, but I usually don't see a need to remove the [iphone] tag.

In summary, I think it's perfectly fine to leave [iphone] and [ios] tags on questions, in addition to [objective-c], although I like to remove [xcode] when it's not appropriate.

Comment: +1 for nuking Xcode without mercy.

Comment: Thx like said before xcode is not a problem (no ambiguity about removing it when needed). I agree with you for iOS tag. Should I keep this question open a few hours to see other point of view ?

Comment: I feel we should synomize [iphone] to [ios] if that's the reason it's still use.

Comment: @ColeJohnson - We've discussed this before: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167511/ios-iphone-ipad-tags, and there was a synonym set up and later broken for these tags: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85188/break-the-ios-iphone-synonym . As stated there, while the tags aren't always used exactly as they should, there are good reasons to keep them separate.