# Rampant [iphone] tag misuse

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

If you look at [the list of questions marked with the [iphone] tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone), you'll see that almost none of them are hardware-specific, which the tag wiki says is the intended usage. I just recently started using SO actively, so I don't know how this is supposed to be handled. I saw the [Burninator Toolkit](https://stackapps.com/questions/4207/burninator-toolkit), but I don't have the reputation to use it or the time to fix a problem this large. What's the solution?

Comment: It's simple. We burn the badtag. :3

Comment: Um... [177,580 questions](http://www.tubechop.com/watch/1366584)?

Comment: It's absolutely insane. If I had to guess I'd say less than 5,000 of those are actually correct tags.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That would be one heck of a burnination.

Comment: Burn [iphone]? You mean like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=qOxQO5vYfDA&t=46)?

Answer (score 6):

An explanation of the history of this tag might help clarify why it's so widely used.

When the site started, iOS as a term hadn't yet been coined, and neither the iPad or the iPod touch had been announced yet. The only iOS device you could develop for was the iPhone, and the OS was called the iPhone OS. Likewise, iOS development was commonly referred to as iPhone development. Those terms remained popular long after the OS was renamed to iOS, and you still hear many people talking about doing iPhone development when they really mean iOS development.

As a result, [iphone] became the go-to tag for anyone developing for the iOS devices, even after the iPad and other iOS hardware came out. It took a while to transition people to [ios] after that term was introduced, and even today there's still inertia around [iphone]. In fact, a couple of years ago, [people tried to point [ios] to [iphone]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85242/135615), rather than the other way around. I talk a little bit about what the consensus was at that time.

My current take on it is that [ios] is now the dominant tag for general iOS questions, but people still do ask questions with only the [iphone] tag when there's nothing device-specific in the question. When I see that, I usually add [ios] to the tags rather than completely replacing [iphone], because there are people who still watch the latter.

Going back and retagging all [iphone] questions is impractical and, in my opinion, unnecessary. I know people want to maintain a perfect taxonomy with tags, but we have to recognize how your average visitor uses them. For a while, the convention was to use [iphone], and there's still some people who do so. Questions in both [ios] and [iphone] still have enough visibility to get answered by experts in those areas, and we can retag the few cases where they might not be getting the attention they need.

I'm more concerned with questions that fall through the cracks due to tags like [ios6] and other versions, where those are the only tags. People watching [ios] or [iphone] alone won't see those, and a lot of them go unanswered. Those need love before questions with these two very popular tags.